# Local contractibility of group of symplectomorphisms for open manifolds

Tags: differential-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

It is well know that for a closed symplectic manifold $(M, \omega)$ the group of symplectomorphisms in locally contractible. The gist of this proof goes as follows.

Given a $\psi \in \operatorname{Symp}(M,\omega)$ that is sufficiently close to the identity in $C^1_{loc}$ topology, we look at the graph of $\psi$ (denoted by $\Gamma(\psi)$) in $M \times M$. And using Lagrangian neighbourhood theorem we can identify a neighbourhood of the diagonal in $M \times M$ with a neighbourhood of the 0-section in $T^*M$. Then using that $\psi$ is sufficiently close to the identity and the  following facts:

Fact 1: If $\alpha : M \rightarrow T^*M$ is an embedding sufficiently close to the 0-section then $\alpha$ is the graph of a 1-form.

Fact2: If $\beta : M \rightarrow M \times M$ is an embedding sufficiently close to the diagonal then $\beta$ is the graph of a diffeomorphism.

we get a correspondence between symplectomorphisms in a small enough neighbourhood of the identity and a neighbourhood of 0 in the vector space of closed forms thus giving us local contractibility.

Unfortunately the proofs of both Fact 1 and Fact 2 that I know of seem to rely on compactness of $M$. So

1) Does local contractibility of group of symplectomorphisms still hold for open  symplectic manifolds? How about for manifolds with boundary?

2) Is the proof similar to the one above i.e., are Fact 1 and 2  true in the non-compact case as well or do we need  new ideas to prove this?

**Edit**

The question as it was originally asked had a small mistake. I shouldn’t have considered $C^1 $topology on a non-compact manifolds as this would not make sense. Instead The question should be phrased in the $C^1_{loc}$ topology i.e $\phi_n \rightarrow \phi$ in $C^1_{loc}$ iff on every compact set $K \subset M$  $\phi_n \rightarrow \phi$ in the $C^1$ sense.